# Cefsharp trigger loaded without assets

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I used `FrameLoadEnd` event to handle my code
but it seems function will trigger when all assets loaded
is there any way to handle main page loaded before assets loaded?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There is http://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/E_CefSharp_IWebBrowser_FrameLoadStart.htm thought without more details it's not clear what your trying to achieve.

Comment: I want do something after source of mainpage loaded and before assets like image loaded

Comment: For what reason?

Comment: just get page's html source

Comment: The third option is http://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/E_CefSharp_IWebBrowser_LoadingStateChanged.htm From experience you are best to wait until the page has fully loaded. There really aren't any other options